# How to animate a model in WebGL?

Tags: opengl, animation, blender, webgl

I created a human model in Blender, exported the vertices and indices into a JSON file and render the model in a browser using WebGL. Now I created a walk and jump animation in Blender and would like to do the same with WebGL.

I saw examples that use a list of vertices for every frame of the animation. Is this the way to go? Do I need to export the vertices for every frame for every animation?

Comment: Animation is a pretty large topic covering scene graphs and arguably too big of a topic to answer on this site other than few links. Here's an answer you might find useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/41649931/128511

Answer (score 7):

You need to implement either something like bones or morphs. As stephelton suggests, a WebGL framework would make this easier.

Since you're using Blender, how about using [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) ?

It already has a [Blender exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender) and there is also a python script to convert objs to the json format the framework uses, in case you need to use other applications.

Among great other projects, it was used for [Ro.me](http://www.ro.me/tech/) and you can see samples of morphs there. You can have a look at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/3-dreams-of-black/source/browse/#git/deploy/files/models/soup) for the models as well.

[image: animation skinning three.js sample]
[image: morph targets three.js sample]

Answer (score 1):

You want to employ some kind of skeletal animation system. I suggest you find a WebGL framework to support this.